# Формирование нового блока вместе со ссылкой

Tags: javascript, html, css

С помощью JS пытаюсь в блоке "block-price" сформировать новый блок с соответствующей номерной ссылкой внутри, на основе атрибутов href и title из ссылки которая лежит в "block-description".
Ссылки и текст формируются, но только во всех блоках "block-price" ссылка "Link name #3".
Что нужно поправить чтобы в первом блоке "block-price" была ссылка "Link name #1", во втором - "Link name #2" и в третьем - "Link name #3"?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let blockPrice = document.querySelectorAll('.block-price');

  blockPrice.forEach((item) => {
    let newTitle = document.createElement('div');
    let description = document.querySelectorAll('.block-description');

    newTitle.classList.add('new-title');
    description.forEach((i) => {
      let name = i.querySelector('.link').getAttribute('title');
      let link = i.querySelector('.link').href;

      newTitle.innerHTML =
        `
          <a href="` + link + `">` + name + `</a>
        `;
    });
    item.prepend(newTitle);
  });
});
```

```css
.list {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 20px;
  justify-content: center
}

.block-price {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.block-description {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item">
      <div class="block-price">
        <div class="new-price">1000$</div>
        <div class="old-price">500$</div>
        <div class="current-price">800$</div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-description">
        <div class="title">
          <a class="link" href="https://s.imgur.com/images/404/cat1weyes.png" title="Link name #1"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="text">Text text text</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <div class="block-price">
        <div class="new-price">1000$</div>
        <div class="old-price">500$</div>
        <div class="current-price">800$</div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-description">
        <div class="title">
          <a class="link" href="https://s.imgur.com/images/404/cat2weyes.png" title="Link name #2"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="text">Text text text</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <div class="block-price">
        <div class="new-price">1000$</div>
        <div class="old-price">500$</div>
        <div class="current-price">800$</div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-description">
        <div class="title">
          <a class="link" href="https://s.imgur.com/images/404/cat3weyes.png" title="Link name #3"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="text">Text text text</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам не нужен второй цикл. Берете элементы `item` и перебираете.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

  items.forEach((item) => {
    let newTitle = document.createElement('div');    
    newTitle.classList.add('new-title');    
    let name = item.querySelector('.link').getAttribute('title');
    let link = item.querySelector('.link').href;   
    newTitle.innerHTML = 
        `
          <a href="`+link+`">`+name+`</a>
        `;        
    item.querySelector('.block-price').prepend(newTitle);   
    
  });
});
```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

  items.forEach((item) => {
    let newTitle = document.createElement('div');    
    newTitle.classList.add('new-title');    
      let name = item.querySelector('.link').getAttribute('title');
      let link = item.querySelector('.link').href;

      newTitle.innerHTML = 
        `
          <a href="`+link+`">`+name+`</a>
        `;        
       item.querySelector('.block-price').prepend(newTitle);   
    
  });
});
```

```css
.list {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 20px;
  justify-content: center
}

.block-price {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.block-description {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item">
      <div class="block-price">
        <div class="new-price">1000$</div>
        <div class="old-price">500$</div>
        <div class="current-price">800$</div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-description">
        <div class="title">
          <a class="link" href="https://s.imgur.com/images/404/cat1weyes.png" title="Link name #1"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="text">Text text text</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <div class="block-price">
        <div class="new-price">1000$</div>
        <div class="old-price">500$</div>
        <div class="current-price">800$</div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-description">
       <div class="title">
          <a class="link" href="https://s.imgur.com/images/404/cat2weyes.png" title="Link name #2"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="text">Text text text</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <div class="block-price">
        <div class="new-price">1000$</div>
        <div class="old-price">500$</div>
        <div class="current-price">800$</div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-description">
        <div class="title">
          <a class="link" href="https://s.imgur.com/images/404/cat3weyes.png" title="Link name #3"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="text">Text text text</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```